# "Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'userCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have log file like this.

[image]

my app.js

> 'use strict';
>
> ```
> /**
>  * @ngdoc overview
>  * @name placementTestApp
>  * @description
>  * # placementTestApp
>  *
>  * Main module of the application.
>  */
>  angular.module('placementTestApp', [
>   'ngAnimate',
>   'ngAria',
>   'ngCookies',
>   'ngMessages',
>   'ngResource',
>   'ngRoute',
>   'ngSanitize',
>   'ngTouch'
>     ])
>  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
>   $routeProvider
>         .when('/', {
>           templateUrl: 'views/beck/partials/home.html',
>           controller:"",controllerAs:"mainCtrl"
>         })
>       // route for the about page
>         .when('/soal', {
>           templateUrl : 'views/beck/partials/soal.html',
>           controller:"",controllerAs:"soalCtrl"
>
>         })
>         .when('/addSoal', {
>         templateUrl : 'views/beck/partials/addSoal.html',
>         controller:"",controllerAs:"addSoalCtrl"
>
>         })
>         .when('/user', {
>         templateUrl : 'views/beck/partials/user.html',
>         //controller: 'userCtrl'
>         controller:"userCtrl",controllerAs:"userCtrl"
>         })
>         .when('/addUser', {
>         templateUrl : 'views/beck/partials/addUser.html',
>         controller:"",controllerAs:"addUserCtrl"
>
>         })
>         .when('/level', {
>         templateUrl : 'views/beck/partials/level.html',
>         controller:"",controllerAs:"levelCtrl"
>
>         })
>         .when('/addLevel', {
>         templateUrl : 'views/beck/partials/addLevel.html',
>         controller:"",controllerAs:"addLevelCtrl"
>
>         })
>         .when('/page', {
>           templateUrl : 'views/beck/partials/page.html',
>           controller:"",controllerAs:"pageCtrl"
>
>         })
>         .when('/addPage', {
>           templateUrl : 'views/beck/partials/addPage.html',
>           controller:"",controllerAs:"addPageCtrl"
>
>         })
>         .when('/cekDb', {
>           templateUrl : 'views/beck/partials/cekDb.html',
>           controller:"",controllerAs:"cekDbCtrl"
>
>         })
>         // route for the contact page
>         .when('/profile', {
>           templateUrl : 'views/beck/partials/profile.html',
>           controller:"",controllerAs:"profileCtrl"
>         })
>         .otherwise({
>           redirectTo: '/'
>         });
> });
> ```

userCtrl.js

```
 'use strict';
  angular.module('placementTestApp'[]).controller('userCtrl',[$scope,userCtrl]);
      function userCtrl ($scope) {
        // body...
        //get user
        $scope.pagedItems = [];
        $scope.get_users = function(){
            $http.get("../controllers/user.php?action=get_users").success(function(data){
                $scope.pagedItems = data;
            })
        }

        //add user
        $scope.user_add = function(){
            $http.post('user.php?action=add_user',
                'user_name' = $scope.user_name,
                'user_email' = $scope.user_email,
                'user_pass' = $scope.user_pass
                ).success(function(data){
                    $scope.get_users();
                }).error(function () {

                });
        }   

        //delete user


        //update user


        //edit user
      }
```

Comment: What is your question? Can you fix your code formatting?

Answer (score 0):

The code formatting is off, but the error message is pointing to this line:

```
angular.module('placementTestApp'[]).controller('userCtrl',[$scope,userCtrl]);
```

You need to put quotes around `'$scope'`, since its purpose at that point is just to instruct angular what to inject into your controller, and there is no actual reference to a particular `$scope` at that point:

```
angular.module('placementTestApp'[]).controller('userCtrl',['$scope', userCtrl]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid `[]` in your `userCtrl.js` file module because you already inject dependency in `app.js` file for same module. Also use `''` (single quotation) in `['$scope', ..` but not in function arguments

Like:

```
angular.module('placementTestApp').controller('userCtrl',['$scope', function($scope) { 
  // your codes here
}]);
```

And ensure that `userCtrl.js` loaded in your `index.html` or where you load all js files.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me you can try this.

```
angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']).controller('userController',userController);
function userController(){
   /* your code */
}
```